# IBM MQ client is unable to reconnect to MQ server intermittently

Tags: .net, windows-services, connection, ibm-mq

**Context:**

We have built a Windows service in C#.NET (4.5). The service listens to IBM MQ (ver: IBM Websphere MQ 8.0.0.6) 24 X 7 and picks up the message for processing when it’s available.

The MQ server goes down every Sunday for a maximum duration of 6 hours. To handle this, we have set `WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS` property as `WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT` and `WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT` to `28800` while creating connection. This means we are asking MQ client to try reconnecting automatically for 8 hours.

We have also registered a callback function to handle connection exception. We keep on getting following log every second or so while MQ is down:

```
MQ delivered an asynchronous event with completion code 0, and reason 2544.
```

As soon as the MQ server is up we also get following exception:

```
MQ delivered an asynchronous event with completion code 0, and reason 2545.
```

**Problem:**

As stated above, the MQ server goes down every Sunday for a maximum duration of 6 hours. Generally, MQ client (.NET service) is able to reconnect but on some occasions the client is not able to reconnect. We are getting same logs even when client is not able to reconnect to MQ. We don’t get any special exception as well.

**Questions:**

1. What could be potential issues?
2. Are we missing any property?
3. Is something missing in MQ server configuration?

Comment: Reason code 2544(MQRC_RECONNECTING) and 2545 (MQRC_RECONNECTED) are expected. Reason code 2544 sent back to application callback to indicate MQ .NET client is attempting to reconnect to queue manager. What reason code your application receives when it fails to reconnect? Have you checked if your queue manager is up before the reconnection timeout?

Comment: Do you get the 2545 even when it fails to reconnect?